# What does "reads before reads" mean in memory ordering?

Tags: multithreading, memory, operating-system, read-write, memory-model

Let's consider this sentence ([Total Store Ordering](https://lwn.net/Articles/576486/)):

> reads are ordered before reads, writes before writes, and reads before writes, but not writes before reads.

I think I almost get the basics:

- Each thread has its own program order (code as it is written)
- In general, CPU may reorder instructions and we must constrain it to exclude incorrect orderings
- CPU may also reorder memory loads and stores and we must constrain those as well
- Current hardware implementation has "serializing instructions" like `mfence` which are invoked by all threads to address both of the problems.
- Hardware typically allows only one dirty cache, so it is all about flushing that cache:

  - Storing thread flushes dirty cache
  - Loading thread requests and blocks until there is no dirty cache
- Kernel developers care about devices other than CPU accessing memory but I don't.

Yet I still fail to understand what does "reads before reads" really mean. It probably means that there are implicit barriers and serializing instructions in those architectures but I can't really tell.

Comment: Probably that reads won't be reordered relative to other reads.

Comment: OP, may I ask where did you get this quote from? Note that neither Sparc nor classic x86 allow load-load reordering here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering

Answer (score 0):

I am so sure I have heard that in the OS course at my uni in Greece, damn, I read it with the voice of the prof. :) Since nobody answered, I will attempt to answer.

Imagine you are the OS, every thread/program wants to perform reads and write. Now, since we are talking about multithreading, a thread may read something another thread has written, like a value of a variable.

Now if thread 1 wants to perform a read of a memory address `x`, and thread 2 wants to perform a read `x` too, it's OK to allow them to read `x` in any order. That's what it means, I think!

Hope it helps somehow, since I know it's not the best answer one could give! :/